# ASP.NET Core - NLog - How can I disable logging for specific route?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, logging, nlog

I have an endpoint /healthcheck for checking if the application is working or not. The other service will call this endpoint for each 5 seconds.

The problem is this is causing lots of log data for /healthcheck requests. Is there any way to configure Nlog to disable logging for specific route on ASP.NET Core?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: it depends on where you log the data. If you are doing in middleware, then you can simply check the request endpoint there and bypass the logs

Answer (score 1):

You can use NLog Filters for that, check [this](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages)

I made a filter programmatically, to to log everything (without Critical level) and ignore routes that contain "SignalR" word:

```
// define a rule for non-exceptions
var nonExceptionsRule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Error, myTarget)
{
    Final = true,
    DefaultFilterResult = FilterResult.LogFinal
};

nonExceptionsRule.Filters.Add(new ConditionBasedFilter
{
    Condition = "contains('${aspnet-Request-Url}','SignalR')",
    Action = FilterResult.IgnoreFinal
});
```

You may not specify any levels in your filter, so that it will be for all levels:

```
var nonExceptionsRule = new LoggingRule("*", myTarget)
{
    Final = true,
    DefaultFilterResult = FilterResult.LogFinal
};
```